# How to "overlay" relationships using Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a series of Sold Menu Item (SMI) nodes (i.e. items that are for sale at a store).  There are Base Menu Items (BMI) that are listed underneath the SMIs that represent the components that make up the SMI.  For example, for fast food, the SMI might be a combo meal and the BMIs would be the Coke, fries and sandwich.  SMI nodes are blue and the BMI nodes are green.  The red nodes represent geographic locations and have their own hierarchy (store -[inherits_from]-> region -[inherits_from]-> market).

SMI/BMI Layers Graph:

[image]

What I'm looking to do is specify the SMIs sold at a market level and have regions and stores inherit
and/or modify those relationships.  In the graph above, I am able to have Store 1234 inherit the SMIs and relationships from it's parent US Market.  I've also attempted to model an example where the US Market sells 4 items and yet a particular Region (NY) only sells 3 items, i.e. the NY Region has a relationship of offers yet the offer is deactivated (property).

Here is the Cypher CREATE statement:

```
CREATE (:Component {value: "Ketchup"})<-[:made_of]-(n1:BMI {value: "Hamburger", 
version: "default"})-[:made_of]->(oz_Beef_Patty:Component {value: "4oz Beef Patty"}) 
<-[:made_of]-(n13:BMI {value: "Hamburger", version: "New York"})-[:can_add]-> 
(n5:Component {value: "Folded Egg"})<-[:made_of]-(:BMI {value: "Folded Egg"})<- 
[:contains {geoId: "USM"}]-(n15:SMI {value: "Folded Egg"}), (n17:SMI {value: 
"Hamburger"})-[:contains {geoId: 1234}]->(n23:BMI {value: "Hamburger", version: 
"Store 1234"})<-[:contains {geoId: 1234}]-(Hamburger_Extra_Value_Meal:SMI {value: 
"Hamburger Extra Value Meal"})-[:contains {geoId: "NYR"}]->(n13)-[:can_add]-> 
(American_Cheese:Component {value: "American Cheese"})<-[:can_add]-(n1)-[:can_add]-> 
(n5)<-[:can_add]-(n23)-[:made_of]->(Onions:Component {value: "Onions"}), 
(Salt:Component {value: "Salt"})<-[:made_of]-(n1)-[:made_of]->(Onions)<-[:made_of]- 
(n13)-[:made_of]->(Salt)<-[:made_of]-(n23)-[:made_of]->(Mustard:Component {value: 
"Mustard"}), (Pickle:Component {value: "Pickle"})<-[:made_of]-(n1)-[:made_of]-> 
(Mustard)<-[:made_of]-(n13)-[:made_of]->(Pickle), (Roma_Tomato:Component {value: 
"Roma Tomato - 2 Slices"})<-[:can_add]-(n1)-[:made_of]->(Regular_Bun:Component 
{value: "Regular Bun"})<-[:made_of]-(n13)-[:can_add]->(Roma_Tomato)<-[:can_add]- 
(n23)-[:can_add]->(American_Cheese), (New_York_Region:Geo {value: "New York Region", 
level: "Region", id: "NYR"})-[:offers {status: "inactivated"}]->(n15)<-[:offers 
{status: "activated"}]-(US_Market:Geo {value: "US Market", level: "Market", id: 
"USM"})<-[:inherits_from]-(New_York_Region)<-[:inherits_from]-(:Geo {value: "Store 
3456", level: "Store", id: 3456}), (n2:BMI {value: "M French Fry"})<-[:contains 
{geoId: "USM"}]-(Hamburger_Extra_Value_Meal)<-[:offers {status: "activated"}]- 
(US_Market)-[:offers {status: "activated"}]->(n17)-[:contains {geoId: "USM"}]->(n1), 
(:Geo {value: "Store 1234", level: "Store", id: 1234})-[:inherits_from]->(:Geo 
{value: "Chicago Region", level: "Region", id: "CHR"})-[:inherits_from]-> 
(US_Market)-[:offers {status: "activated"}]->(:SMI {value: "M French Fry"})- 
[:contains {geoId: "USM"}]->(n2), (Hamburger_Extra_Value_Meal)-[:contains {geoId: 
"USM"}]->(n1), (n17)-[:contains {geoId: "NYR"}]->(n13), (Regular_Bun)<-[:made_of]- 
(n23)-[:made_of]->(oz_Beef_Patty)
```

When I execute the following query...

```
MATCH (geo:Geo)-[:inherits_from*0..]->(geos:Geo)
WHERE geo.value = "Store 1234"
WITH geos
OPTIONAL MATCH (geos)-[o:offers]->(smis)-[c:contains]->(bmis)
WHERE c.geoId in [(g1:Geo)-[:inherits_from*0..]->(gs:Geo) WHERE g1.value = "Store 1234" | gs.id]
return geos,smis,bmis
```

I get back what I expect, the products that were specified at the US Market level.  If, instead, I specify Store 3456, the node Folded Egg appears with relationships from both geographies.  Ideally, I would like the relationship at the Region to "cancel" the US Market relationship to Folded Egg in the results output.

Results:

[image]

Does anyone know how I achieve this behavior whereby relationships are "layered on" or "overlay" each other?  Or perhaps another way of modeling my objects to better achieve the above functionality?  I don't want to have to repeat relationships at the Region level that are already present at the US Market level.  Thanks in advance!

In my comment above, I'm not trying to create relationships in the model, just remove relationships for nodes that already exist in the query results.  For example, I tried the following query...

```
MATCH (geo:Geo) 
WHERE geo.value = "Store 3456"
CALL {
    WITH geo
    OPTIONAL MATCH (geo:Geo)-[o1:offers]->(smis)
    RETURN collect(smis) as totalSMIs, collect(geo) as totalGeos
}
CALL {
    WITH geo, totalSMIs, totalGeos
    OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[:inherits_from]->(geos1)-[:offers]->(regionSMIs)
    RETURN apoc.coll.union(apoc.coll.removeAll(collect(regionSMIs), totalSMIs), totalSMIs)  AS totalSMIs2, 
        apoc.coll.union(totalGeos, collect(geos1)) as totalGeos2
}
CALL {
    WITH geo, totalSMIs2, totalGeos2
    OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[:inherits_from]->(geos1)-[:inherits_from]->(geos2)-[:offers]->(marketSMIs)
    RETURN apoc.coll.union(apoc.coll.removeAll(collect(marketSMIs), totalSMIs2), totalSMIs2) as totalSMIs3, 
        apoc.coll.union(totalGeos2, collect(geos2)) as totalGeos3
}
WITH totalSMIs3, totalGeos3
UNWIND totalGeos3 AS x
UNWIND totalSMIs3 AS y
MATCH (x)-[:inherits_from*0..]->(geos)-[o:offers]->(y)
WHERE o.status <> "inactivated"
RETURN DISTINCT totalSMIs3, totalGeos3
```

to remove nodes that are linked at different hierarchy levels and I'm still getting all of the wrong nodes.  What I'm trying to do with the above is to remove the relationship that is being overridden.  For example, in the data, the US Market sells Folded Egg ([:OFFERS {status: activated}]) yet the New York Region overrides that selection with it's own relationship ([:OFFERS {status: inactivated}]).  When I execute the code above, I still see the two relationships between the two geos and Folded Egg.  I only want the node and relationship from the New York Region and not from the US Market b/c the New York Region has it's own relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct to say that when you create the data, you need to check if there is an existing relationship at the market level before you create another relationship at Region level that is, between New York Region to SMI-Folded Egg.

> perhaps another way of modeling my objects to better achieve the above
> functionality

Below is the query to do so.  1. Find the SMI (folded egg) 2. Create a loop where you will check if the US Market has an offer to this SMI  3. If not found then create a relationship between this region (New York) to this SMI

```
MATCH (Folded_Egg:SMI {value: "Folded Egg"})
MATCH (New_York_Region:Geo {value: "New York Region"})
WITH Folded_Egg, New_York_Region
FOREACH (_ in CASE NOT EXISTS((:Geo {value: "US Market"})-[:offers]->(Folded_Egg)) when true then [1] else [] end | 
CREATE (New_York_Region)-[:offers]->(Folded_Egg) )
RETURN Folded_Egg, New_York_Region
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I'm actually trying to modify the relationships that are returned in my query as opposed to creating relationships within the database.  The relationships that I need already exist, I'm just trying to have Cypher return the lower level relationships instead of the higher level ones that have been "replaced".

Comment: I see. Cypher will still return that relationship from Region to SMI because it will show whatever the data is in the database. It is up to you on how to handle it in the application that consumes the data whether to show or not to show it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a query that traversed the geography hierarchy and only added new nodes using UNION and WITH statements.  Below is the statement...

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[o:offers]->(storeSMIs)-[:contains]->(storeBMIs)-[:defined_as]->(storeVers)
WHERE storeVers.version = o.version AND geo.value = "Store 3456"
RETURN storeSMIs as totalSMIs, storeBMIs as totalBMIs, storeVers as totalVers
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[o:offers]->(storeSMIs) WHERE geo.value = "Store 3456"
WITH collect(storeSMIs) as storeSMIs
OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[:inherits_from*1..1]->()-[o2:offers]->(regionSMIs)-[:contains]->(regionBMIs)-[:defined_as]->(regionVers)   
WHERE regionVers.version = o2.version AND NOT regionSMIs in storeSMIs
    AND geo.value = "Store 3456"
RETURN regionSMIs as totalSMIs, regionBMIs as totalBMIs, regionVers as totalVers
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[o:offers]->(storeSMIs) WHERE geo.value = "Store 3456"
WITH collect(storeSMIs) as storeSMIs
OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[:inherits_from*1..1]->()-[o2:offers]->(regionSMIs) WHERE geo.value = "Store 3456"
WITH storeSMIs, collect(regionSMIs) AS regionSMIs
OPTIONAL MATCH (geo)-[:inherits_from*2..2]->()-[o3:offers]->(mktSMIs)-[:contains]->(mktBMIs)-[:defined_as]->(mktVers)   
WHERE mktVers.version = o3.version AND NOT mktSMIs IN storeSMIs
    AND NOT mktSMIs IN regionSMIs AND geo.value = "Store 3456"
RETURN mktSMIs as totalSMIs, mktBMIs as totalBMIs, mktVers as totalVers
```